# Is it OK to duplicate parent field in child table for performance?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance

I have a very complicated query which involve more than 10 tables. Some parent tables are loaded only to search on one field. I wonder if I can copy this field in the child table (this data is never updated), so that I don't need to load the parent table in my query.

I've always learned that I should not store the same data in two different place, but maybe it's "allowed" for performance ?

For example, imagine a country table, a city table, and a street table. Having the country code in the street table would speed up some complicated queries.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you test? If having a `countryID` column in the `street` table helps you index your table and optimize the queries - say by adding an index on `(countryID, cityID, streetName)` which you can't do otherwise as the columns are spread in 2 or 3 tables - then go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is called **denormalization**.

The rule of thumb is "normalize till it hurts, denormalize till it works."  Denormalization should follow the access pattern of your queries.  If you have a common query that goes from joining on 10 tables to just a few with just a small bit of duplication, go for it!

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I'm glad to see there is a "rule of thumb" that match my feeling :)

Comment: Especially, you gave me the right keywords to search in google (I'm french and a selflearning in db). There is a bunch of great article about this subject I can now found in seconds, like this one http://blog.codinghorror.com/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal/